# Multiple Elements Visible--Need function to determine which is higher on page?

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, visible

I am using the following code, which I garnered from another post from a few years back, to identify elements that are fully visible in a user's browser:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}
```

I'm then checking for multiple elements and scrolling to them if the function returns:

```
        if(isScrolledIntoView($('#hero')) && (!($('#hero').hasClass('selected')))){
            $('div, img').removeClass('selected');
            $('#hero').addClass("selected");
            $("#nav-dock").animate({top: '200px'});
        }

        if(isScrolledIntoView($('#home-digital-trans')) && (!($('#home-digital-trans').hasClass('selected')))){
            $('div, img').removeClass('selected');
            $('#home-digital-trans').addClass("selected");
            $("#nav-dock").animate({top: '800px'});
        }
```

But in some rare cases, I'm having BOTH elements visible at the same time. So I'm trying to figure out how I can write a function that can choose the "higher" element if more than one element is visible.

I don't even know where to start--I'm not a jQuery programmer really. Maybe using position() on all elements with class .nav and then returning the element that is closest to the top and visible?

Comment: You know about `jQuery waypoints` ? http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Yeah--I saw that while searching around. From what I can tell, it doesn't really solve this issue.